# How to use Blenders GUI?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, interface

I was making a game with blender like creating buttons and stuff but um... I don't know how to use Blenders API, or GUI. I wanted to create functioning buttons and creating user input on the screen like you would in Tkinter for python. I am really confused on what to do with Blenders GUI stuff... I meanm like how to access and create stuff with it. So is there a way to use Blenders API (mainly I want to have control over blenders GUI to do what ever I want)?

And when I import blenders game engine like this "import bge" or "from bge import *" but it says model don't exist. What should I do? am I missing a module?

Comment: I don't think you can use the `bge` module in the viewport, if that's what you are trying to do.. See the [API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).

Comment: well I looked at the refrences and he/she does the "import bge" so how come he/she can do it but I can't?

Comment: I am also having trouble adding fire to my ship and I don't know what to do. I wan to animate blue fire when a key is pressed. This is hard man. I guess I see why game developers need millions of developers for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to learn the Blender interface while working on your game, but I suspect that this is more of a challenge than you need to take on. If you're totally new to Blender, I think you'll find it salutary to gain some familiarity with the Blender and the Blender interface tools by working through one (or both) of two online courses, one by James Chronsiter at [[http://www.cdschools.org/Page/455]](http://www.cdschools.org/Page/455%5d), with video supplements at [[http://4chron.home.comcast.net/~4chron/CDCADTutorials.htm]](http://4chron.home.comcast.net/~4chron/CDCADTutorials.htm%5d), or alternatively Neil Hirsig's course at [[http://gryllus.net/Blender/3D.html]](http://gryllus.net/Blender/3D.html%5d). These will give you a solid introduction to the interface, and some introduction to the BGE.

There are also a number of books available that can help, including free downloads from Wikibooks [[http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro]](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro%5d), and a book by John Blain (a bit out of date, but still using basically the same interface as the current edition), [[http://download.blender.org/documentation/pdf/John%20M%20Blain%20-%20An%20Introduction%20To%20Blender%203D%20-%20A%20Book%20For%20Beginners%20%282011%29.pdf]](http://download.blender.org/documentation/pdf/John%20M%20Blain%20-%20An%20Introduction%20To%20Blender%203D%20-%20A%20Book%20For%20Beginners%20%282011%29.pdf%5d)

Comment: Wow! I was really worried that I never develop my game. I also have one more question. When I rum my game by pressing "P" in the Game Engine my background and stuff want load correctly. What should I do to correct this? My controlls for my object works fine but the game excludes my images and everything.

Comment: I can't help much with the Blender Game Engine, as I use Blender to create assets for a game with its own engine, and have not yet ever had occasion to use it. Both Hirsig and Chronister do talk about BGE in their courses, and if that doesn't answer your question, there are books and ebooks by other author which deal with that more exhasutively.