# How can you color smoke based on the smoke's temperature?

Tags: rendering, materials, smoke-simulation

As seen in the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQMZ2mE-8HI), the smoke is colored based on its temperature. I know how to use the attribute to color smoke based on flame and density, but how can I use it to color based on the smoke's temperature?

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible in cycles yet, that was rendered in BI.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I don't agree, how is it a feature request?

Comment: @gandalf3 True.... it isn't *directly* asking for it to be implemented.

Answer (score 8):

## Blender Internal

As [GiantCowFilms said](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19476/599), this isn't currently possible in Cycles (but probably will be in the hopefully-not-too-distant-future). In the meantime, it is possible with BI:

1. Setup your simulation. See [How to simulate a gas?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12181/599) and the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Smoke) for more detailed info.
2. Add a new material to the smoke domain, set the type to *volume*, and set the density to `0` (if you haven't already):

   [image]

   Note that this step is not needed if you used *quick smoke* to create your domain
3. Add a new texture, set the type to *Voxel data*, and select your domain object:

   [image]

   At the bottom of the texture settings, in the *Influence* panel, enable *Density* so that the texture influences the density of the texture:

   [image]
4. Add another new texture, again with the type set to *Voxel data* and your domain object selected.  But this time set the *source* to *Heat* (there are also some fun options like *Velocity*). This will give you a black and white map of the temperature variations inside your smoke domain.

   To colorize it, enable *Ramp* and set the color ramp to the colors of your liking. In my screenshot I moved the ends in a bit, as extreme temperatures like those at the ends of the ramp were not being reached in my simulation. (as an alternative to altering the color ramp, you could also increase the *Contrast* by adjusting the value slider below the ramp):

   To make the color influence the color of the smoke, enable *Reflection color* and *Transmission color* in the *influence* panel:

   [image]
5. Make sure the coordinates of both textures are set to *Generated* in *Texture > Mapping*. It should be by default, however I've noticed it behaving strangely recently (i.e. while writing this answer :P)

### Result

(click on the image for a nicer version)

[image]

For some reason there is some flickering in the heat channel. I've noticed this with *velocity* before as well. (bug?)

## Cycles

While it's not possible currently (as mentioned before), it is possible to create a similar effect to the video you linked in your question. By using the [color blending features](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.65/Smoke_Simulation#Colored_Smoke) that were added since that video was made:

1. Set the *color* on the emitter objects:

   [image]
2. This color can then be accessed via the attribute node:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't possible right now in cycles**. You will have to use the internal render engine. The feature will probably be added soon though

Comment: Answer is obsolete/incorrect. Remove it possibly?