# Can't Change Color Smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have change color in tab Flow. But I still in black color. Please help me!
This picture is my blender display.
[image: My Blender Display]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you color smoke based on the smoke's temperature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19474/how-can-you-color-smoke-based-on-the-smokes-temperature)